# How to include math.h on a PIC?

Tags: c, mplabx

I know `<math.h>` can be a large amount of code to include, but want to test out something using `sinf()` on a low-cost PIC.  Is there a slimmed down version of `math.h` that is being used by the XC8 Compiler?  Why is neither `sin()` or `sinf()` defined?

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DELTA_RAD   0.01

void main(void) {
  float x = 0.0;
  float y;

  while (1) {
    x += DELTA_RAD;
    y = sinf(x);  // <-- ERROR on this line

    // Do something with y
  }
}
```

Comment: Just in passing, `<math.h>` has very little code. It has **prototypes** for functions that you can use. When you **use** those functions the code for the functions you used gets linked in.

Comment: Thanks, @PeteBecker.  I actually wasn't sure about that.

Comment: @RossRidge, updated to mod by `2 * PI`.  Thanks.

Comment: Modulo might turn your float into an integer

Comment: You will generally also have to link an implementation of the C Standard Library, some mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library

Comment: @rhughes: Generally yes, but this is not a general question. This is a question about PIC compilers.

Comment: I'm not sure about XC8 but you need `-lm` option to link `math.h` in some compilers

Comment: why would you modulo the argument to a trigonometric funtion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The approach to low-memory coding is to not use math.h, and instead use INTEGERS, lookup tables, interpolation, and maybe Taylor Series (or other) expansions.  Figure out how much error you can tolerate (and how that error accumulates), and design your code to that.

Nice trig approximation review at http://www.ganssle.com/articles/atrig.htm

Comment: +1 I was amazed by the accuracy and speed of a simple DFT algorithm I entirely coded entirely in integers and look up tables.

Comment: Not just low memory micros, but also (maybe especially) micros with low clock speeds.

Comment: Yup. A 360° sin LUT with 1° resolution is easy enough- it can be done with a 90-element LUT (thus fitting in a single page for the baseline PIC limitations) and a bit of math to flip sign etc. for the remaining three quadrants.

Comment: I'm always amazed by how many people never quite understand that you can express 0.5 as 5 using units of tenths, or 500 using units of thousandths.  You need to be careful of multiplication causing overflows, or integer division propagating errors.  The latter can often be prevented by doing divisions last.

Comment: For embedded systems, [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) is recommended if more precision is needed. It's also used in hardware implementations for trancendental functions.

Answer (score 8):

You should actually look at the math.h file and figure it out (tm). Also it would be helpful if you mentioned the actual PIC part number you're trying to use.

To answer your actual question, you are including the math.h file correctly.

As you can see from the #ifdef/#endif statements, if you look at the math.h file, the PIC12 core is not supported for transcendental functions. That means nothing with a 12-bit instruction word such as PIC16F54 or PIC12F509. For more capable cores, it is supported for double sin(double), not float.

I would suggest considering a PIC18 core (over PIC16) if you intend doing floating point calculations. The price difference is typically pretty nominal, and you can get very high clock speeds (32MHz or 64MHz). Or hand craft some assembler/integer code like it was 1995.